# Emulate NFC tag in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, nfc

I am in the development of the NFC application only with Android Emulator. so I wanted to emulate the NFC tag through the Emulator. so can I emulate the Same using the emulator the way for the Location and SMS/call service is provided.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you have to use [FakeTagsActivity](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/src/com/example/android/nfc/simulator/FakeTagsActivity.html) for mocking NFC data. You can find this in the sdk samples. The android emulator does not support what you want.

Comment: Link isn't working anymore. Maybe https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/3c407385303dc44906342147368451f2ef528cff/samples/NFCDemo/src/com/example/android/nfc/simulator/FakeTagsActivity.java is the same but the link doesn't really look permanent to me.